# whats the difference between ob_flush and ob_end_flush?

Tags: php, output-buffering

i am confused about the PHP functions `ob_flush()` and `ob_end_flush()`. 
About the function `ob_flush` the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) says

```
The buffer contents are discarded after ob_flush() is called.This function does not destroy the output buffer like ob_end_flush() does.
```

**i am  confused about the words `discarded` and `destroyed` here**. Even if the buffer contents are discarded in case of `ob_flush()` they cant be accessed and even if they are destroyed as in case of `ob_end_flush()` they cant be accessed.
Then whats the difference between these two functions?

**UPDATE:**

In response to [JamWaffles answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355356/whats-the-difference-between-ob-flush-and-ob-end-flush/7355384#7355384) I dont understand the significance of *deleting everything in the buffer but keeping the buffer vs deleting the whole buffer(freeing it)* because PHP has no concept of pointers and you cant get the address of buffers so it should be immaterial whether you keep the empty buffer with you or you free it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think in this case they mean the same thing. `ob_flush()` is used when you want to flush *parts* of the page to the client, whereas `ob_end_flush()` flushes the entire buffer, then destroys the buffer. What `ob_flush()` does is delete everything *in* the buffer, but keeps the buffer itself so more data can be put into it after the `ob_flush()` call.

---

I'll try to explain better.

#### Discarded

Let's say I have a nice, bright orange plastic bucket. This is my **buffer**. I then get some sand, representing the **contents of the buffer**, and fill the buffer (bucket) up. I then pick this bucket with sand in it up and pour it into a sandpit, which is my **client**. You'll notice the sand is gone, yet the bucket remains. This is what is meant by `the buffer contents are discarded` - the buffer itself can be re-used (filled up with sand again). In memory terms, the memory is emptied but not freed, so it can be filled again.

#### Destroyed

Now, if we take our bucket again, fill it up with sand once more, empty the sand out and then set fire to the bucket because we don't require it any longer, that's called **destroying the buffer**; the data *in* the buffer is gone, **but so is the buffer itself**. In memory terms, the memory is freed for other use.

---

Is this significant in PHP, without pointers, the OP asks? Well, it depends what you want to do. If you're processing a long page, and want to (for example) send the header and sidebar to the client while you process the rest of the page for sending after it's done, use `ob_flush()`.

If you want to flush something to the client without any more output after it, use `ob_end_flush()`.

---

I mean absolutely no disrespect in talking in a rather patronising tone; I wanted to make an analogy to make the definitions as clear as possible.

Comment: "delete everything in the buffer, but keeps it"? how can you keep it when u delete it? sorry i didnt get you

Comment: when you say `ob_flush()` flushes parts of the page,do you mean that it flushes only innermost buffer in case of nested output buffers, while `ob_end_flush()` flushes all buffers instantly even if there is nesting of `ob_start()`?

Comment: Sorry about that! I've edited my question. In response to your second comment, I mean that `ob_flush()` allows more output to be buffered and sent to the client, whereas `ob_end_flush()` doesn't.

Comment: sorry but still i dont get u. whats more output and wats less output. Is there any size limit? sorry but that is difficult for me to groke.and about your edit in your answer i ll edit my question to better communicate what i dont understand about that.

Comment: please see my update to the question. and sorry i m not good at expressing myself so it might be difficult to understand

Comment: i understood what you meant by discarded and destroyed. But is it significant in a language like PHP with no pointers?Thanks

Comment: It depends what you want to do. If you're not echoing anything else after the flush call, use `ob_end_flush()`; this ends the script output, whereas `ob_flush()` allows more output to be sent to the client.

Answer (score 5):

ob_flush does not turn off output buffering

Comment: But [`ob_end_flush()` does](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) :-)

Answer (score 1):

`ob_end_flush()` displays everything from the buffer, then destroys the buffer. `ob_flush` does the same, but does not destroy the buffer just clears it.

`ob_flush()` =

```
ob_end_flush();
ob_start();
```